# I can't show the name of logged user on the page

Tags: php, mysql

please could you help me to show the username on the page?

I got this **error**:

> **Notice**: Undefined index:

```
<?= $_SESSION['auth']->pseudo; ?>
```

Comment: Undefined index mean $_SESSION objects doesn't contain auth key

Comment: Do you have session start? Do you have setted session variables? Without more code is impossible to help you.

Comment: try this $_SESSION['auth']['pseudo'];

Answer (score 0):

This is the begining

```
<?php 
session_start();
//require 'functions.php';


$title = "Accueil | Wintrack";
require 'include/header.php';

require 'dbconnection.php';
logged_only();
```

Comment: it should be in post edit not here because here all  answer place